# How to dynamically open a new page using this php code?

Tags: php, html

I have this php code which basically retrieves information from a MySQL database and displays it in a table.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if ( !$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zendesk_data") ){
        $output="Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;      
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT id, subject, requester FROM escalationreview";
        if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $output="<table> 
                <tr align='left'>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Requester</th></tr>";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $output.= "<tr><td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td></tr>";
                }
                $output.="</table>";
            } else { 
                $output= "0 results"; 
            }
        } else {
                $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
    echo $output;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what my index page looks like:

[image]

Now, what I want to achieve is that, when I click in the ticket ID, it opens up that ticket page. So, for example, if I click in ticket with ID 1234 it opens 1234.php and if I click in ticket with ID 1235 it opens 1235.php and so on.

I'm new to php and honestly I have no clue how to achieve this.

Thanks to anyone willing to assist and sorry if this seems like a dumb question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a common page to pass the ticket ID and retrieve the details.

First, you have to wrap the ticket ID as an anchor link to the page you want to redirect. The link also should have the Ticket ID as a parameter.

```
$output.= "<tr><td><a href='ticketpage.php?tid=".$row["id"]."'>". $row["id"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td></tr>";
```

Then, create a new page with the name `ticketpage.php` (You can change this if you need to) and retrieve the ID we passed via the link earlier by using the code example below:

```
<?php 
    $tid = $_GET['tid'];
    // Remaning code
```

Comment: Maybe OP has rewrite rules and wants `1234.php`? In which case, just modify to `<a href="'.$row['id'].'.php">` - Although your way is the way to go but I'd recommend using `$tid = isset($_GET['tid']) ? (int) $_GET['tid'] : 0;` on second code.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I have tried Harshana's code but it does not retrieve the 'tid'. I have created the ticketpage.php page and when I click on the ticket ID it takes me to the ticketpage.php page but it does not retrieve the ticket id, the url stays just like ticketpage.php?tid=

Comment: Am I missing something maybe?

Comment: Try adding a single quote after the row['id'] in anchor link 

```$output.= "<tr><td><a href='ticketpage.php?tid=".$row["id"]."'>". $row["id"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td></tr>";
```